# paypal Chained Payment not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a laravel project using paypal's adaptive chained payments used. However the chained payment isn't working as expected. Here's my pay request.

```
$payRequest = new \PayPal\Types\AP\PayRequest(
            new \PayPal\Types\Common\RequestEnvelope("en_US"), 
            'CREATE', 
            '/dash/settings/payment/error',
            'USD', 
            $reciversArr, 
            '/dash/settings/payment/done'
        );
```

This request works and i get the paykey. Then i do the redirection so the user could do the payment. How ever instead of creating a payment which can be executed later, the api seems to create and execute it at the same time. I checked this on production as well. Nothing seems to be working and the documentation is very unclear. Has anybody ever implemented this successfully ?